# getting a connection object from dataSource in groovy

Tags: groovy, datasource

Our Application has a Datasource.groovy defined.
I am using it in a controller like this

```
import  javax.sql.DataSource
class xxx {
 javax.sql.DataSource dataSource

 def myappsql = new Sql(dataSource)
 myappsql.row(querystring) .....

}
```

I need to get connection object from the datasource, is this possible directly like this :

```
 Connection conn = myappsql.getConnection()
```

Since this is giving me error, does it have to be a `groovy.sql.Sql` to do this call?

I am trying to avoid creating a connection object from scratch, with user, password and url string and instead reuse the one declared in datasource.

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dependency-injecting the `DataSource`, you can dependency inject the `SessionFactory`

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory
import groovy.sql.Sql

class SomeService {

    static transactional = true
    SessionFactory sessionFactory

    void someMethod() {
        // Get a connection object that participates in the current transaction
        def connection = sessionFactory.currentSession.connection()

       // Use the connection to create a Sql instance
       Sql sql = new Sql(connection)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guys for the tips, for now I am getting invdividual variables required for the connection from the configurationholder.config.datasource.url , ...username, ...password etc and then creating the connection..so I have removed the hardcoding for the connection variables

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do:

```
conn = myappsql.datasource.connection
```

I believe you're getting the error as you [construct the Sql object with a datasource](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#getConnection%28%29)

Comment: It isnt working .. running myappsql.dataSource.getconnection() gives me an object, but its not the same type as java.sql.Connection. I printed out the conn object and it says "Transaction-aware proxy for target Connection  from DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@2e7f4425]" where as it should be something like "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@21ef3faa" . I tried using the other connection object in my Jasper Report call and it isnt working..

Comment: @pri_dev What type is it?  Do I have to guess again?  What does `println myappsql.datasource?.connection?.class?.name` print out?